# Flutter Firebase BLoC pattern

Tags: firebase, flutter, business-logic

I want to know how to manage `BLoC` pattern for `Firebase`.
I couldn't find any example of `BLoC` for `Firebase` so it might be broad but forgive me.
I saw some basic `BLoC` implementation but those were basically fetch data or updating view in a active way not passive way also not through database(almost API JSON stuff).
So, I want to see how to handle some `BLoC` pattern for `Firestore` like get followed(passive way), when user update own profile info something like that.
Does anyone lead me to the correct way?
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What BLoC pattern gives you is nothing more than a data stream that can be updated adding new data through the `stream.sink`.

Using Firestore you already have a data stream, so you might not need BLoC.

If your application requires a more complex logic you might update you BLoC data adding a listener to a firestore ref in the root widget to have db and bloc always in sync (maybe with multiple blocs for multiple db refs).